# Convert Date (YYYY MM DD HH:MM:SS) to Decimal Day (YYYY MM DD.ddddd)

Tags: python, date, decimal, astronomy

I have a script built that takes a date and time of an observation at a telescope and converts it to just a date with a decimal day. This script also takes in half the exposure time and adds it to the decimal day so that I can get the most accurate astrometric calculation. This is then submitted to The Minor Planet Center that only accepts the time of observation in Year Month Day.XXXXX What is the most accurate way to 5 decimal points to do this? This is the current way I use, yes it is very messy but it does get me the decimal day. Occasionally it is off by one second in the time conversion.

```
expmpc = float.("10")
utcstartmpc = "05:45:19.03"
datempc = "2015-02-14"


ddexposure = expmpc/(60.0*60.0*24.0)
ddexposure = round(ddexposure, 5)
seconds = int(utcstartmpc[6:8]) / 60.0
minutes = (int(utcstartmpc[3:5]) + seconds) / 60
hours = (int(utcstartmpc[:2]) + minutes) / 24
hours = round(hours, 5)
expadd = str(hours + ddexposure)
datempc = datempc.replace("-", " ")
utcmpc = "C%s%s" % (datempc, expadd[1:])
utcmpc = utcmpc.ljust(17, "0")
```

As you can see this is very messy and it involves rounding a lot of data and I believe I am losing accuracy with the rounding. The finished outcome of the code leaves a time such as this:
C2015 02 14.23986

Is there a module that works better?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Since this is about [tag:astronomy] and sub-second precision: Does the Minor Planet Center expect the time in [Universal Time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Time) (common in astronomy) or [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (civil timekeeping)?

Comment: @LukasGraf: [UTC is kept within 0.9 seconds from UT1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DUT1) i.e., it is probably ok if you need only 5 digits after decimal point (the actual value of [`DUT1`](http://datacenter.iers.org/eop/-/somos/5Rgv/getTX/17/bulletind-121.txt) in February is less than `1e-5` of a day). Anyway, [The Minor Planet Center expects UTC here](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/iau/info/Astrometry.html#report)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that uses more of the built-in time/date modules (and I *think* it does what you want):

```
import time
import datetime

def my_date_converter(date_in):
    parse_str, _ = date_in.split(".")
    date_str, time_str = parse_str.split(" ")
    parsed_time = time.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M:%S")
    total_seconds = datetime.timedelta(hours=parsed_time.tm_hour,minutes=parsed_time.tm_min,seconds=parsed_time.tm_sec).total_seconds()
    seconds_in_day = 86400.0
    decimal_seconds = total_seconds / seconds_in_day
    utcmpc = "C%s%s" % (date_str.replace("-", " "), str(round(decimal_seconds, 5))[1:])
    utcmpc = utcmpc.ljust(17, "0")
    return utcmpc


def main():
    to_convert = "2015-02-14 05:45:19.03"
    converted = my_date_converter(to_convert)
    print "%s => %s" % (to_convert, converted)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Example output: `2015-02-14 05:45:19.03 => C2015 02 14.23980`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the excellent astropy library? They have a package to deal with time and conversions: [astropy.time](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/time/)

Answer (score 0):

You could separate your problem into 2 tasks:

- get `datetime` object that represent UTC time from the input `expmpc`, `utcstartmpc`, `datempc`
- convert datetime object to string in the `Year Month Day.XXXXX` format.

#### Get `datetime` object from the input `expmpc`, `utcstartmpc`, `datempc`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

expmpc = "10"
utcstartmpc = "05:45:19.03"
datempc = "2015-02-14"
dt = datetime.strptime(datempc + " " + utcstartmpc, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
dt += timedelta(seconds=int(expmpc))
```

#### Convert `datetime` object to string in the `Year Month Day.XXXXX` format

```
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

s = dt.strftime("C%Y %m %d.")
day_fraction =  dt - datetime.combine(dt, time.min)
s += ("%.0f" % (100000*day_fraction / timedelta(days=1)))
# -> C2015 02 14.23992
```

Note: the result is slightly different from the one in your question (`92`  vs. `86` at the end).

In Python 2, you need to replace `td / timedelta(1)` with `td.total_seconds() / 86400`.

Here's another way:

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> assert day_fraction.days == 0
>>> '%.0f' % ((day_fraction.seconds*10**6 + day_fraction.microseconds) / 864000)
'23992'
```

All arithmetic operations before the true division are performed with infinite precision.

Yet another way also produces `92`:

```
>>> from datetime import timezone
>>> ('%.5f' % ((dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp() % 86400) / 86400))[2:]
'23992'
```